# MoPub errors when switching to 64 bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, mopub

I just changed to iPhone 5 64 bit on the XCode simulator to test my game, and the MoPub ads and I got a lot of compile errors.

```
"ld: warning: ignoring file
//Game/src/Classes/MoPubSDK/AdNetworkSupport/Millennial/SDK/libMMSDK_5.1.1.a,
missing required architecture x86_64 in file
//Game/src/Classes/MoPubSDK/AdNetworkSupport/Millennial/SDK/libMMSDK_5.1.1.a
(3 slices)ld: warning: ignoring file
//Game/src/Classes/MoPubSDK/AdNetworkSupport/Millennial/SDK/SpeechKit/SpeechKit.framework/SpeechKit,
missing required architecture x86_64 in file
//Game/src/Classes/MoPubSDK/AdNetworkSupport/Millennial/SDK/SpeechKit/SpeechKit.framework/SpeechKit
(3 slices)ld: warning: ignoring file
/Game/src/Classes/MoPubSDK/AdNetworkSupport/GoogleAdMob/SDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a,
missing required architecture x86_64 in file
//Game/src/Classes/MoPubSDK/AdNetworkSupport/GoogleAdMob/SDK/libGoogleAdMobAds.a
(3 slices)
```

I reached out to MoPub and they said it might be something wrong with the Millennial and AdMob files, but I'm a loss what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problem. I added MoPub to my app and it no longer compiled - throwing similar errors as yours.

I made the following changes to get it to build:

1. Removed "libGoogleAdMobAds.a" from my project (found in MoPub>AdNetworkSupport>GoogleAdMob>SDK)
2. Downloaded the latest Google Mobile Ads iOS SDK (6.9.3)
3. Added "libGoogleAdMobAds.a" from latest Google Mobile Ads iOS SDK to my project, same directory where it existed before

I'm now able to build and run on my iPhone 5S. Kind of a hack. Need to dig deeper, see if there's anything else i might be missing.